# How to open an EMACS file in OS X by double-clicking on it, using the `emacsclient` command?

Tags: macos, emacs, automator, emacsclient

I want to open an org-mode file selected in the *Finder*, by double clicking on it. But since I use Emacs in *daemon-mode*, I want to use the `emacsclient` command for that.

Thus the primary idea was to wrap the command `emacsclient -c posixPathToFile` in an AppleScript *App* to open it.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fileAlias to the selection as alias
    set fileName to name of fileAlias
    set posixPath to POSIX path of fileAlias
end tell

-- tell application "Emacs" to activate

try
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -c " & quoted form of posixPath
end try
```

I know some `set` commands are not needed. Let's assume this script is saved as `Xemacs.app` and that I associate this app to always open `.org` file.

Using this App does not work by double-clicking on the file, but rather if I select the file in the Finder and then call the *Xemacs.app* independently. Why ? I'm not confident enough with AppleScript to figure out what happens.

So the workaround was to use the Automator service

```
  on run {input, parameters}

    set posixPath to POSIX path of input


    tell application "iTerm" to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -c " & quoted form of posixPath

    return input

end run
```

The service is saved as **'Open in Emacs'**

Now selecting a file and right-clicking and callig Service > "Open in Emacs" works and opens the file.

What is wrong with the first approach ?

Comment: How about making an application with platypus and running your script from there, and make your favorite file types associated with that platypus application?

Comment: idea was not to use a third party tool

Comment: Here is a related thread entitled "*Emacsdaemon and Emacsclient on Mac*" that has a few examples:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/141/emacsdaemon-and-emacsclient-on-mac and here is another related thread on reddit:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1wu2ja/a_tip_for_os_x_users_using_emacs_daemon/?st=j639vmk6&sh=8bb51e73  Google keywords:  "**emacsclient automator app emacs finder**"

Comment: thanks, I already found those links but none are really answering my question and the Ascrpit are the same as mine. My problem is how to wire the component so that double-clicking opens the file. The automator approach is only a temp. workaround.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I solved my issue. The problem comes from my misunderstanding of the difference between *ScriptEditor* and the *Automator*. If I use the Automator to create an App and use the former script instead of creating an App using the ScriptEditor, then it works as expected.

One can simplify the process by creating an App in Automator and running a shell script instead of wrapping the command in Ascript.

[image: shell script Automator]